# javascript popup does not close the popup once download is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am downloading the file in the through window open and then after its download I need to close self.close the window. It works in the Chrome but not in IE.

function ExportFile(t){
$(this) = $(t);

window.open('test.com','_blank','height=150,width=200').setTimeout(function(){$(this).close();},1000);
return false;
}

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer's console?

Comment: I just get close is not a function

Comment: Unless you have extremely specific client requirements for a legacy system stuck on IE, that browser has officially reached end of life and has no support from Microsoft anymore

Comment: I am using EDGE browser

Comment: Wait this won't work in Chrome either, not sure how you're seeing success there. You need to assign the result of `window.open` to a variable and call close against that.  `var newWindow = window.open('stackoverflow.com','_blank','height=150,width=200');
    
setTimeout(function(){newWindow.close()},1000);`

Comment: @jmcgriz. It does not work this way because if the file it relatively large it will close the window before the download is finished. I need to be able to download the file first and then close the window

Comment: It sounds like you need to rework the code then - I just edited what you had written there to be functional. You'll need to find a way to track the download and close based on that rather than this 1000ms timeout you currently have

Comment: well the question is how

Comment: do you have access to the page at `test.com`? how is the file downloaded?

Comment: It streams to the browser. the file get build through the of header name="content-desposition" value="inline filename=test.cfm" cfsavecontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" variable="#readBinary(workbook)#"

Comment: do you own the page you are opening? If that's the case can you please share what's in that page. How do you manage the file download?